# Get all objects that has an array that contains a specific value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of objects called students that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    student_id: '1',
    student_name: 'student 1',
    courses: [
      { course_id: 'dxgk22452', course_name: 'courses 1' }, 
      { course_id: 'asdf9d2d', course_name: 'courses 2'},
      { course_id: 'h355dsf4', course_name: 'courses 3'}
    ]
  },
  {
    student_id: '2',
    student_name: 'student 2',
    courses: [
      { course_id: 'asdf9d2d', course_name: 'courses 2'},
      { course_id: 'glld9432d2', course_name: 'courses 4' }
    ]
  },
  {
    student_id: '3',
    student_name: 'student 3',
    courses: [
      { course_id: 'dxgk22452', course_name: 'courses 1' }, 
      { course_id: 'glld9432d2', course_name: 'courses 4' }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am trying to figure out the best way to get all objects that contain a specific course id.

I tried `students.where(courses.course_id == "dxgk22452")` with no luck and could not find a post with my specific situation.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: When posting a code sample please take an extra moment to ensure that the code is valid. I had to correct numerous errors in your sample to make it valid.

Comment: If the target `:course_id` were `'dxgk22452'` I assume you would want to return `[students[0], students[2]]`. Correct? If so, to keep your code  *DRY* (don't repeat yourself) you may wish to instead return `[0,2]`. That assumes you don't intend to chain the return value to another method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate twice to select those hashes, where their `courses` include at least one hash where its `course_id` is equal to `dxgk22452`:

```
data.select { |e| e[:courses].find { |f| f[:course_id] == 'dxgk22452' } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Given an array:

```
students = [
  {
    student_id: '1',
    student_name: 'student 1',
    courses: [
      { course_id: 'dxgk22452', course_name: 'courses 1' }, 
      { course_id: 'asdf9d2d', course_name: 'courses 2'},
      { course_id: 'h355dsf4', course_name: 'courses 3'}
    ]
  },
  {
    student_id: '2',
    student_name: 'student 2',
    courses: [
      { course_id: 'asdf9d2d', course_name: 'courses 2'},
      { course_id: 'glld9432d2', course_name: 'courses 4' }
    ]
  },
  {
    student_id: '3',
    student_name: 'student 3',
    courses: [
      { course_id: 'dxgk22452', course_name: 'courses 1' }, 
      { course_id: 'glld9432d2', course_name: 'courses 4' }
    ]
  }
]
```

Return the students whose courses include the given value:

```
students.select { |student| student[:courses].any? { |course| course[:course_id] == 'dxgk22452' } }
=> [
  {
    student_id: '1',
    student_name: 'student 1',
    courses: [
      { course_id: 'dxgk22452', course_name: 'courses 1' }, 
      { course_id: 'asdf9d2d', course_name: 'courses 2'},
      { course_id: 'h355dsf4', course_name: 'courses 3'}
    ]
  },
  {
    student_id: '3',
    student_name: 'student 3',
    courses: [
      { course_id: 'dxgk22452', course_name: 'courses 1' }, 
      { course_id: 'glld9432d2', course_name: 'courses 4' }
    ]
  }
]
```